# Dygraph: rollPeriod on 1 of the Y axis, or on selected series only; not on the all series

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am implementing a mixed graph, bars and line, with dygraph 2.0.
My custom bar plotter works fine with the standard line one.
My lines series have a rollperiod set, but since the bars have their own Y values, I need them to not being averaged...
It seems at the moment that the rollperiod can only be set for all series, or none, but not for a specific Y axes definition, or even a specific series...

Is this possible ? any workaround ... ?

Thanks in advance,
JC

Answer (score 0):

I end up removing the rollPeriod from the graph option, and to calculate the rolling average manually per serie, before loading the graph...

```
function averageRollData(data, serie){

    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        var left = data.length - i;
        var inc = Math.min(4, left);
        var val = 0; // data[i][serie];
        var div = inc;
        for (var x = 0; x < inc; x++){
            var v = data[i + x][serie]
            val += v;
            if (v == null) div--;
        }
        data[i][serie] =  val / div;
    }
}
```